# How to translate products for multiple stores in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, multistore, localisation

I'm trying to set up Magento 2 to handle several stores, and each store in two languages.

Structure is something like this:

```
Website1
  Store1
    Danish
    English
  Store2
    Danish
    English
  ...
WebSite2
...
```

How do I translate a product. Most of the documentation I have found on this topic, says I should open the product (the product is in danish as default) change store view to Store1/English and translate the product.

Now this is easy if I have one store. But if I have several stores then I have to translate same product several times.

Is there a better way to do it?

Same problem when translating categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look out this.

On the Admin Panel, Products > Inventory > Catalog.

Find the product that need to be translated, and open it in the edit mode.
In the upper-left corner, select Store View for the translation display

Click OK to confirm.

In the edit mode, you need:

Uncheck the Use Default Value checkbox in the right of the field.
Enter the translated text into the field.

Ensure that all necessary text fields are translated well, including image labels and Alt text, Search Engine Optimization fields and any Custom Options information.

Save to complete.

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-translate-products-into-other-language-magento-2.html

**Edit**

To make it automate you need to write a script that change product name store level.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614700/programmatically-change-product-attribute-at-store-view-level) is an example that works for Magento 1.
Hope you got a idea!!

Comment: But this is exactly the problem I described. If I have 100 stores then I have to do this 100 times, each time I want to change a text.

Comment: @CasperSkovgaard, I have edited my answer, look it

Comment: Thanks. This was not the answer I hoped for. But it seems to be the Magento way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Could not find any answer to this so I developed a module that saves a product on all the other store views that have the same Locale as the currently selected store view when you edit a product.

My employer allowed me to Open Source it.
https://github.com/tuango-magento/LocaleManager

If you can please mark this answer as correct so future people can see it!

Thanks

Comment: nice idea! Is it really works good?

Answer (score 0):

Our approach so far has been to remove-from-websites, save, and re-add the products to those websites.

In your case, you're consistently using Danish as your default product language, so any change to the Danish text should already update automatically for all stores/store views that are set to use the default text.

If you need to add or change the "shared" English text of a product and want it reflected on all the stores that serve this product, you can take note of which *websites* have the product, under the *Product in Websites* heading.

Then, switch to a store that has the English text (like Website1->Store1->English), change the text, and uncheck *all other websites but the one you changed* that you want to update the English text for.

Now save, re-check the websites you unchecked, and you'll be given options for each Store in those websites to copy the data values from another Store – just select the store you changed for English, and any Danish (default) store for Danish, I suppose.

At least, this copies over all the English text, meta, etc. to the other English stores.